# What is the Venn diagram for XPath, XQuery, and XQuery Update?

Tags: xpath, xquery, xquery-update

Note: in all of the following, when I refer to "XQuery" I mean the latest version of XQuery. Ditto for XQuery Update.

[True or False] XQuery is a superset of XPath. That is, the XQuery language consists of all the stuff in XPath plus more.

Eek! I didn't specify the version of XPath.

[True or False] XQuery is a superset of XPath 1.0

[True or False] XQuery is a superset of XPath 2.0

[True or False] XQuery is a superset of XPath 3.0

[True or False] XQuery is a superset of XPath 3.1

[True or False] XQuery Update is a superset of XQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery 3.1 is a superset of XPath 3.1. Or, more generally, for a given version of XQuery, it is a superset of the same version of XPath.

XQuery Update extends XQuery. XQuery Update remains at version 3.0 and has not been updated to account for XQuery 3.1's support for maps and arrays.

Comment: Moreover, XQuery Update 3.0 is only a WG Note - it's unfinished work. The main new feature relative to 1.0, namely allowing an expression to return both a result and a pending update list, proved controversial and I think it basically hit a block where there wasn't enough consensus - or enough effort - to take it forward.

Comment: Note also that there are some minor differences that mean XPath 3.1 isn't a pure subset of XQuery 3.1. The main one is that XQuery 3.1 expands entities and character references, XPath doesn't. That's because XPath is designed for embedding in XML documents where they have probably been expanded already, and you don't want to do it twice.

Comment: What version of XQuery Update does Saxon support? XQuery Update 3.0? XQuery Update 1.0? If the latter, then Saxon's XQuery Update is a superset of XQuery 1.0 which is a superset of XPath 1.0, right?